# linux bash while do loop plus variable value

Tags: bash

I need to get swap memory size in bytes from linux so i im executing this command:

```
{ read firstLine; while read f t s u p; do echo $s; done;} < /proc/swaps
```

It returns:

```
523260
523260
```

And i need to return:

```
1046520
```

i try using:

```
{ read firstLine; while read f t s u p; do echo $s++; done;} < /proc/swaps
```

but i know that is incorrect of using $s++, i im new to bash so if someone have clue or idea how do i need to increment $s variable with value that is read?

If i have for example:

523260
  256523

I need to get output:

779783

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to sum up the values in the 3rd column, do:

```
 awk 'NR>1{a+= $3} END {print a}' /proc/swaps
```

To do the sum your way, you can do:

```
{ total=0; read firstLine; while read f t s u p; do : $((total += s)); done; echo $total; } < /proc/swaps
```

Comment: thanks that is the code that i need..thank you...and big vote for nice answer

Comment: @John you should `accept` the answer rather than *big vote* it.

Comment: will do in 3min..system does not accept it before

Answer (score 2):

In bash, `$((expr))` represents the artithmetic evaluation of expr.

```
A=1
B=2
echo $((A+B))
```

will print 3.

So you need to first read A and B from /proc/swaps and then add them after they have been assigned.

Note however that this only evaluates integers to integers.